# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to implement both a PCA and t-sne algorithms to cluster the embeddings resulting of using ImageBind. For this, using scikit-learn v.1.3.2 library in python v.3.8.18, I'm trying to use the sklearn library but the error mentioned in the title keeps popping at:

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA 
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
```

This is the traceback of the error:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 4
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 4 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
      5 from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
      7 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py:83
     69     # We are not importing the rest of scikit-learn during the build
     70     # process, as it may not be compiled yet
     71 else:
   (...)
     77     # later is linked to the OpenMP runtime to make it possible to introspect
     78     # it and importing it first would fail if the OpenMP dll cannot be found.
     79     from . import (
     80         __check_build,  # noqa: F401
     81         _distributor_init,  # noqa: F401
     82     )
---> 83     from .base import clone
     84     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     86     __all__ = [
     87         "calibration",
     88         "cluster",
   (...)
    129         "show_versions",
    130     ]

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:19
     17 from ._config import config_context, get_config
     18 from .exceptions import InconsistentVersionWarning
---> 19 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     20 from .utils._estimator_html_repr import estimator_html_repr
     21 from .utils._metadata_requests import _MetadataRequester

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils'
```

I'm using Anaconda to admin my environments and Jupyter Notebook to run the program and visualize the results.

I've checked that I'm using the latest version available of sklearn as well as that the packet .utils exists in my version of sklearn. I've tried to add the isolated library using both pip and conda in my environment, and installing the previous version (1.2.2). I've also checked that the path is included. Nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be?

Edit: Hey, I'm new to both python and stackoverflow so please try to be nice:)

Comment: Can you provide the traceback of the error?

Comment: You have not shown any code that refers to `sklearn.utils`, therefore the error must be happening in other code that you have not shown us.  It's very hard to help when you do not show us the code that has the actual error.  As Nick said, please post the full error traceback message.

Comment: This seems pretty mysterious. I have two ideas: First, 1.3.2 is not the most recent version of sklearn - it's the most recent version which is compatible with Python 3.8. So one idea would be to upgrade to Python 3.9 or later, and try the newest sklearn version. Second, Someone else had a similar error that was caused by long paths being disabled on Windows. https://superuser.com/questions/1469221/environmenterror-when-installing-sklearn/1567726#1567726 Is this caused by the same thing? Can you provide what operating system you're using?

Comment: I have tried the same code on a test environment using python3.9 and sklearn 1.4.1.post1 and the error disappeared, but the thing is in order for ImageBind to work I have to use python v.3.8.18. I've tried using earlier versions of sklearn compatible with my python version and the output is still the same error. Also, I've checked what you mention in that post about the LongPathsEnabled property and it was already set to 1. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: `Cell In[1]` is telling that this doesn't happen in "vanilla" Python, but in some Jupyter/notebook flavour. Please specify what your environment is. As the problem happens right at the beginning, you could consider putting those imports into an actual `.py` file, and see how they behave when you try running it from the command line.

Answer (score -1):

'ModuleNotFoundError' means that the python executable could not find the module. This implies that the module was not installed for that python executable. If you are using a virtual environment or a conda environment, you have to

- make sure you install the package in that same environment
- check for the package in the `site-packages` of that particular environment (`conda list scikit-learn`), and
- make sure to have the environment activated when you do the install and run python.

When using conda, and trying to debug this, it's also advisable to make sure that you don't have PYTHONHOME or PYTHONPATH set in your environment, since those could be confounding variables.

Comment: Hi! I definitely did everything that you have recommended before I posted this and the error still popped up. Any other ideas?

Comment: I believe it is not possible that the error still popped up if you followed all those steps (assuming your python environment is otherwise ok and is a regular conda environment for a recent python). So, my only other idea is to double-check what you did. Otherwise, you could try posting to the discuss.python.org Help.